# Hide / Delete tweet from own timeline - whilst still keeping tweet visible to @ recipient

Tags: twitter

I want to send a tweet to someone using @username but I don't want it visible on my timeline. Ideally I could send them a direct message, but they don't follow me so I can't do that.

Is there a way I can send them a normal tweet and then hide/delete it from my public timeline, but still have the tweet available for them to view? (I don't mind if it shows up on their timeline, just not mine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter doesn't support that method of conversation. I believe you could accomplish this on Facebook, but with Twitter the privacy features are much less comprehensive.